# What is the exact behavior of ExecutorService.submit (in terms of queuing requests)?

Tags: java, executorservice

I want to use an `ExecutorService` that uses a single thread. And now I am inserting requests (via submit) on a higher rate than that thread can deal with them. What happens?

I am specifically wondering:

- Are there any guarantees on ordering - will tasks be executed in the exact same order?
- Is there a (theoretical) limit on which the ExecutorService will start throwing away incoming requests?
- Out of curiosity: what changes when the service is using a pool of threads?

(sure, I can assume that some queue might be used; and that the Oracle implementation just "does the right thing"; but I am actually wondering if there is a real "spec" somewhere that nails down the expected behavior)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you created a fixed thread-pool `ExecutorService` with `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);` (or `newSingleThreadExecutor()`) then [the Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool-int-) clearly specifies what happens.

---

> Are there any guarantees on ordering - will tasks be executed in the exact same order?

A fixed-thread pool uses a `LinkedBlockingQueue` to hold pending tasks. Such queue implements a FIFO strategy (first-in-first-out) so the order of execution is guaranteed.

---

> Is there a (theoretical) limit on which the ExecutorService will start throwing away incoming requests?

Quoting the Javadoc:

> If additional tasks are submitted when all threads are active, they will wait in the queue until a thread is available.

Every incoming request will be added to an unbounded queue so there is no limit and no requests will be rejected (so the theoretical limit is `Integer.MAX_VALUE`).

---

> Out of curiosity: what changes when the service is using a pool of threads?

If you mean, "what changes if there are more than 1 thread in the fixed thread pool", then nothing. The queue will still have a FIFO nature and there will be no limit on this queue. Otherwise, it depends on how you create the thread-pool.

Answer (score 2):

I take it you are getting your `ExecutorService` via [`Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor())?

> Creates an Executor that uses a single worker thread operating off an unbounded queue. (Note however that if this single thread terminates due to a failure during execution prior to shutdown, a new one will take its place if needed to execute subsequent tasks.) Tasks are guaranteed to execute sequentially, and no more than one task will be active at any given time. Unlike the otherwise equivalent newFixedThreadPool(1) the returned executor is guaranteed not to be reconfigurable to use additional threads.

So:

> Are there any guarantees on ordering - will tasks be executed in the exact same order?

*Tasks are guaranteed to execute sequentially.*

> Is there a (theoretical) limit on which the ExecutorService will start throwing away incoming requests?

*Operating off an unbounded queue.* So as large as memory/the backing store of the queue will allow. Commonly `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

> Out of curiosity: what changes when the service is using a pool of threads?

Depends on how you create the `ExecutorService`. You can create with bounded queues if you wished, or with a queue that did not use FIFO (such as [`PriorityBlockingQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/PriorityBlockingQueue.html). The documentation for [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) gives a good overview of your different options.

Comment: unbounded queue => limited by memory available or maximum size of the queue (which often is `Integer.MAX_VALUE`).